# What's the difference between defining properties with { } vs =>?

Tags: c#

Is there a difference between the two syntax below? Is there any reason that one of them is preferred over the other?

```
public string PropertyA { get => throw new NotSupportedException(); }

public string PropertyB { get { throw new NotSupportedException(); } }
```

Comment: That second one isn't valid C# FYI

Comment: Does [any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910985/what-is-the-difference-between-getter-only-auto-properties-and-expression-body-p) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522877/what-is-the-difference-between-expression-bodied-syntax-vs-getter-syntax-on-il-l) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764532/what-is-the-assignment-in-c-sharp-in-a-property-signature/31764663#31764663) questions help you?

Comment: Your first one was actually OK (though it still is) those two lines are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only syntactic sugar.

```
public string PropertyA => throw new NotSupportedException();
```

and

```
public string PropertyB { get { throw new NotSupportedException(); } }
```

compile to the same byte-code.

The expression body is just a shorter way of making a read-only property.

I think it looks nicer in certain cases, but it's a style preference.